# Импорт csv в SQLite | Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, sqlite3, csv

Нужно импортировать `csv` файлы в БД под управлением `QSLite` с использованием `Qt C++`? Парсинг не вариант.
В гугле толком ничего не нашел. `.import` непосредственно из `Qt` делать нельзя, предлагают делать системный вызов, запускать в фоне `SQLite` и уже из него делать импорт. Похоже, адекватное решение, но оно должно быть кросплатформенным.
Также, слышал что есть какая-то библиотека по работе с `SQLite` в `Qt` (не через `QSqlDataBase`), говорят, что ее использовать удобнее, но найти не смог.

Comment: А почему парсинг не вариант? вполне себе. Базовая реализация пишется за пару часов.

Comment: Уверен что уже есть готовое решение, а изобретать велосипед не хочу.

Comment: можно и готовые взять. Например https://github.com/iamantony/qtcsv Правда вставку придется ручками написать (но это один цикл).

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле да, всё не так просто. Нет нормального выхода в данной ситуации, но есть, например, такой велосипед без всего лишнего https://dustri.org/b/import-cvs-to-sqlite-with-qt.html